# Ind-etale vs weakly etale

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, etale-cohomology, descent

In [this article](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/proetale.pdf) Bhatt and Scholze consider ind-etale and weakly etale maps of affine schemes. We have two (easy) statements, proven in Prop.2.3.3(1) and (5):

-- any ind-etale map is weakly etale,

-- weakly etale maps satisfy fpqc-descent.

Moreover, it is stated (right after the proof of Prop.2.3.3) that the second claim fails for ind-etale maps. Do someone know

1. An example of a weakly etale map (of affine schemes), which is not ind-etale, resp.
2. An example of an ind-etale map (of affine schemes), which violates fpqc-descent?

Note that such examples must be of non-finite presentation, as weakly etale + of finite presentation is equivalent to etale, and etale is fpqc-local on the target.

Comment: (1) is answered in Example 4.1.12 (due to de Jong) in the linked paper. This is an example of a weakly etale map that is Zariski locally (on the base) ind-etale but not ind-etale itself. I didn't understand (2) but perhaps the same example helps there?

Comment: Thank you! This answers (1). But, as far as I can see, not (2). By (2), I meant an example of an fpqc-cover $A \rightarrow A'$ and a non-(ind-etale) --but necessarily weakly etale-- map $A \rightarrow B$, such that $A' \rightarrow B\otimes_A A'$ is ind-etale.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the example actually gives such an example with A ---> A' being a Zariski cover.